# Remote debugging Meteor / Nodejs with Atom

Tags: node.js, meteor, atom-editor, remote-debugging, node-inspector

Can anyone help me using Atom for remote debugging a Meteor / Node app on another machine?

Have my meteor app with node inspector `--inspect-brk` running on a linux machine:

```
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:24010/3a1f6bec-6f4d-439a-b086-af78cc27c9ea
```

And on my windows machine i have the Atom editor and the source code.

I tried out different atom-debug packages, but to me they seem only to work when both Atom and Node / Meteor are on the same machine and also Atom can launch the meteor or node app itself.

In my case i want to attach to the remote debugger to a running instance on the other machine.

Does anyone know how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify an IP address to the inspect-brk parameter to get it to work remotely. You message is binding to 0.0.0.0 which cannot be seen remotely.

I think the format is —-inspect-brk=your.ip.address.here:portnumber entering a valid IP address fo the server and the port number you wish to debug on. This is from memory as I cannot see my startup code as I type this.